# What minimum license would I need to use this MS Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-list-allchannels?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I have a product that uses this API on the backend to fetch all of the channels available to the user in their Teams environment. They provide me their Teams credentials when they configure the integration. I was asked which license the user would need in order to have access to this Graph API and couldn't find a clear answer anywhere.

I think the client is looking for a definitive "E1 would not work, both E3 and E5 work". As far as I can tell, any license that gives a user access to Teams would give them access to this API?

I have tried asking management for a single license at every level to test, but that got shut down.

Comment: microsoft graph api doesn't depend on any license.... we only need an Azure tenant, then create Azure AD app in this tenant, then we could use this app to generate access token to call graph api, for example we can call `/me` or `/user` endpoint to query user profile. No license is required. But if we want to use graph api to send email, then we need the account which is used to play the role as sender to have a license so that the api could be call successfully. But it doesn't mean we couldn't call the sending email api without a license, it just bring an error result.

Comment: The same as the api you mentioned, it just a "query" api which is used to list all channels, I'm afraid we don't need any license to assign to a specific user to let the user have the ability to call this api....

Comment: If you can access Teams client, that license will work.